# float right won't work

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to float the social icons to the right of the page, but for some reason it won't work.

But the text at the top of the page floats perfectly.

Here is a fiddle:
[check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFWde/)

```
<div class="social">
  <a href="/"><img src="img/twitter.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" /></a>
  <a href="/"><img src="img/google_plus.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Google" /></a>
  <a href="/"><img src="img/linkedin.png" width="32" height="32" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
  <a href="/"><img src="img/facebook.png" width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XKuaT/)? I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 clear:both
```

add the above css in social css

Comment: May I offer you a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZFWde/2/) to show that in action?

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 940px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;

}
#header {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mast-head {
    width: 940px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent !important;
    position: relative;
}
a.logo-txt {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
a.logo-txt #logo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.personalisation {
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: right;
}
.welcome {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.social {
    margin: 100px 0px auto;
    float: right;
    width:100%
}
.social a{
    float:right;
}
​

#nav{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-width:1px 0;
  list-style:none;
  margin-top: 160px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav li{
  display:inline;
}
#nav a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
#nav ul{
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:left;
}
#nav ul li{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, the outcome was the same as putting clear:both;

Comment: It doesn't work in my browser though with the rest of the code.

Comment: did you check if the new css is loaded?